# what is the cardinality of a Null set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Does the cardinality of a Null set is same as the cardinality of a set containing single element?
If a set A contains Null set as its subset, then the null set is taken into account to calculate the cardinality of set A or not?

Comment: The cardinality of empty set is zero, the cardinality of a set containing a single element is 1.

Comment: Please share your thoughts on the problem so far :)

Comment: What kind of null set?

Comment: @leo For example If a set A contains Null set as its subset, then the null set is taken into account to calculate the cardinality of set A or not?

Comment: It may help to review the definition of cardinality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality But you'll be hard pressed to find a bijection from a set with 0 elements to one with 1 or more elements.

Comment: the set $A:=\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ has cardinality 1, since it contains 1 element (that is $\emptyset$). Here the null set is considered as element of $A$, its own cardinality is not relevant (the set $B:=\{ \{\mathbb{R}\} \}$ still has cardinality 1).

Comment: @Milly , i got it.Null set's own cardinality is zero, but if it is a subset (an element ) of some other set, then it will be counted. Right?

Comment: Yes, in a "set of sets" (like $A$) the null set is counted as an element.

Comment: okay, i got it! 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The cardinality of the emptyset is $0$ whereas the cardinality of a finite set is the number of elements in the set.

More precisely, there's a bijection between a finite set and a set with the form $\left\{0,... ,k-1\right\}$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then we say the cardianlity of this set is $k$.

Of course, a set may contain other sets (including the empty set). Every set contained is a member as much as a number would be, so in your case: $\left| \left\{ \emptyset \right\} \right| =1 $ since the set contains only one member which is the empty set.

Answer (score 2):

Simply said: the cardinality of a set S is the number of the element(s) in S.

Since the *Empty* set contains **no** element, his cardinality (number of element(s)) is 0.

If a set S' have the empty set as a subset, this subset is counted as an element of S',  therefore S' have a cardinality of 1.